# Notepad++ Regex Search

Tags: notepad++, regex

I am attempting to isolate all numbers and letters that are not 9 in my example below.

RHB|1|9

After some research I feel like I am getting close, though the "|" seem to make things difficult when using Regex. Is there a way to use a single character placeholder to count out the "|1|" then search for all other numbers and letters?

Comment: The `|` is a logical `OR`. The token `[^9]` matches any character `NOT` the digit `9`.

Comment: That helps! How would sequentially check for just numbers after that? Also, is there a way to check for "|" in "RHB|1|9"?

Comment: To check for a character special to RegEx, you must escape the character with backslash. For example, to check for a backslash, you must use `\\\`.

Comment: So, to find "|" I use ` | `?

Comment: You would use `\|`.

Comment: Thank you!! So last thing. How do I check to make sure that after RHB|1|9 are all numbers?

Answer (score 1):

To match all letters and numbers except the number 9 then you do `[a-zA-Z0-8]`.